# Loading C# DLL via reflection, but apply App.config

Tags: c#, reflection, app-config

I am using something like the following to load DLL's in my C# app.

```
foreach (String s in Directory.GetFiles(".", "*.dll"))
foreach (Type t in Assembly.LoadFrom(s).GetTypes())
```

But it does not apply the App.config settings for those binaries. Is there a programatic way to load these settings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi have a look at ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration on MSDN.  This allows you to read in config types (for users) at runtime.

Comment: I was able to simply run the following code in the constructor of the classes I am loading into memory ...

onfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(null, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

Thanks mate.